# Error when using the std::allocator in the template class

Tags: c++, allocator

Trying to figure out how to use std :: allocator.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename A>
struct vector_base
{
  A       allocator;
  T*      data;
  size_t  size;
  size_t  space;

  vector_base(const A &alloc, size_t n)
    :allocator(alloc), data(alloc.allocate(n)), size(n), space(n)
  {}

  ~vector_base() {allocator.deallocate(data, space);}
};

int main() {
  std::allocator<int> my_allocator;
  vector_base<int, std::allocator<int>> vector(my_allocator, 10);

  return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

> error: passing ‘const std::allocator’ as ‘this’ argument discards
>   qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>        :allocator(alloc), data(alloc.allocate(n)), size(n), space(n)

Comment: `alloc.allocate(n)` you try to call a non-const member function on a `const` reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alloc` is a `const&`, you're trying to call `allocate` on it which is a non-const method, that's not allowed.

Call `allocate` on your initialized member instead:

```
  vector_base(const A &alloc, size_t n)
    :allocator(alloc), data(allocator.allocate(n)), size(n), space(n)
  {}
```

Comment: I would suggest not depending on the order in which the data members are declared. I would put `data = allocator.allocate(n)` in the function body. This way, the code doesn't break if someone moves the declaration of `allocator` after `data`.

Comment: @L.F. Can't be sure OP runs 11+, but yeah usually you would do that

Comment: I think you misunderstood. By “body” I mean the body of the constructor, not in-class member initializer ;-)

Comment: wouldn't compiler still move initialization around, because order of initialization is predefined? Though, what may happen, is that someone changes order of fields in class' declaration. THEN it is a problem.